# Read input files from args just by declaring their sum and a delay for processing

Tags: java, loops, input, args

This is a tricky one for me since I haven't tried it again.

So I am trying to import a specific number of input text files to my program and specify a delay.
Let me explain:

```
java -jar program.jar 5 10
```

This is just an example since the numbers can vary.
In this example I want to read 5 input files and then pass each one to a method after 10 seconds.

Every input file will be named: input[1...n].txt
input1.txt is passed into a method which does some stuff and then after 10sec input2.txt should enter.

I have no idea how to do this. I understand that I have to look for args[0] files in the directory of the file, but how do I look for input**1**.txt?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fileNumber = args[0];
        int delay = args[1]
        Q2fix ks = new Q2fix(args[0]);
        ks.fill();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a loop to check for each numbered file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int delay = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    for (int i=1; i <= fileNumber; ++i) {
        String filename = "/some/path/to/input" + i + ".txt";
        Q2fix ks = new Q2fix(filename);
        ks.fill();
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

I am assuming here that your `delay` is already in milliseconds.  If it be in seconds, then you would want to divide by 1000 before calling `Thread#sleep`.  And `Thread#sleep` tells the current thread to sleep for some amount of time.